# Increment for loop by a fraction/ range of values in Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, for-loop, oracle19c, nested-for-loop

How could we increment value by .25 instead of default 1 in a **for** loop of a stored procedure - oracle 19c?

Also, is it possible to use an array of numbers as a loop values? If not, please advice how to implement it.

For instance,

**fctr1** - passing -4 as fct and fctr1 needs to be incremented by .25 until 4

**fctr2** - range of non periodic value such as 5,7,10,14,15,21

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure sp_test
   ( fct in number )
is
BEGIN
    for fctr1 in fct..4 ///increment by .25
         loop
            dbms_output.put_line(fctr1);
            for fctr2 in ///range of non periodic values
            loop
                  dbms_output.put_line(fctr2);
            end loop;
        end loop;
END;
/
```

Comment: increment steps was not added until 21c.  So you have to increment in the loop

Comment: Or you will need to use some brain cells. For example, to loop from 3 to 5 by 0.25 increment, you can do something like `for i in 12 .. 20 loop` ... and in the loop use `i/4` instead of `i` in every occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a version prior to 21c you cannot specify an increment value in `for`. But you can replace it with a `WHILE` statement where you can (well actually must) do own incrementing; using any desired value your want.  
As far as the non periodic values you step back - to the schema level. Create a collection as a 'table of integers', populate that collection with the values, pass as that collection/array as another parameter. Something like:

```
create or replace procedure sp_test
   ( fct     in number 
   , fct2    in non_periodic_values_t
   , by_incr in number default 1
   )  
is
   l_fct number := 1;
begin
  while l_fct <= fct
  loop 
     dbms_output.put_line('For l_fct ==> '   ||  l_fct ); 
     
     for fct2_ndx in 1 .. fct2.count
     loop
        dbms_output.put_line('     ' || fct2(fct2_ndx)); 
     end loop;
     l_fct := l_fct + by_incr; 
     
  end loop;
end;
```

Since you have a number collection you can even pass the 3 values of a traditional for *loop (start, stop, increment)*.

```
create or replace procedure sp_test2
   ( fct     in number 
   , fct2    in non_periodic_values_t
   , for_val non_periodic_values_t  default  non_periodic_values_t(1,4,1) 
   )  
is
   l_fct number := for_val(1);
   
begin
  while l_fct <= for_val(2)
  loop 
     dbms_output.put_line('For l_fct ==> '   ||  l_fct ); 
     
     for fct2_ndx in 1 .. fct2.count
     loop
        dbms_output.put_line('     ' || fct2(fct2_ndx)); 
     end loop;
     l_fct := l_fct + for_val(3); 
     
  end loop;
end;
```

See [examples here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=23a84fc7343c2176d528479e506fb759).

Answer (score 3):

Just multiply the limits by 4 in the `FOR` loop and then divide by 4 in the output:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure sp_test
   ( fct in number )
is
BEGIN
  for fctr1 in (fct*4) .. (4*4) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(fctr1/4);
    dbms_output.put_line(5);
    dbms_output.put_line(7);
    dbms_output.put_line(10);
    dbms_output.put_line(14);
    dbms_output.put_line(15);
    dbms_output.put_line(21);
  end loop;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b84b6142218806144c3e52b00123274)*